# Airflow 1.10: Task duration failing

Tags: python, airflow

After upgrading from Airflow 1.9 to 1.10 I'm no longer able to see Task Duration in the web GUI. When I click on Task Duration I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/airflow-YvxPQJVU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/airflow-YvxPQJVU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/airflow-YvxPQJVU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/airflow-YvxPQJVU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/airflow-YvxPQJVU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/airflow-YvxPQJVU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/airflow-YvxPQJVU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 69, in inner
    return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/airflow-YvxPQJVU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 368, in _run_view
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/airflow-YvxPQJVU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 758, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/airflow-YvxPQJVU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/utils.py", line 270, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/airflow-YvxPQJVU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/airflow-YvxPQJVU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 1551, in duration
    fails_totals[dict_key] += tf.duration
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Any idea what is causing this?

This is only happening with my old DAGS. New DAGS created after upgrading does not have this problem.

Comment: Have you tried running an `airflow upgradedb`?

Comment: yes, but thanks for suggestion

Comment: This is a known bug. It has PR pending. https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/4032

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the rows for your older records have a `NULL` on the `task_fail.duration` column. Running a manual query against the database may fix you right up: `UPDATE task_fail SET duration=0 WHERE duration IS NULL` -- assuming you're okay with changing the records.

Be sure to snag a backup first too, just in case.